# How can i use Uri instead of FileDescriptor on addTimedTextSource() method?

Tags: android, video, uri, file-descriptor

I want to show subtitle (.srt) with my videos (.mp4)
I'm fetching datas as a 
JSON and decoding it, E.g

Video Url :
`http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/Amshrstry.S02E01.HDTV.x264.mp4`

Subtile Url :`http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/Amshrstry.S02E01.HDTV.x264.srt`

I tried this, it works like a charm, but i cant use raw folder to read subtitle, my all data fetchin from my website (Video Url and Subtitle Url) so i want to read subtitle from url.

Tried code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);

try {
    player.addTimedTextSource(getSubtitleFile(R.raw.sub),
            MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
    int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(
            TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT, player.getTrackInfo());
    if (textTrackIndex >= 0) {
        player.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Cannot find text track!");
    }
    player.setOnTimedTextListener(this);
    player.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}


private String getSubtitleFile(int resId) {
String fileName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resId);
File subtitleFile = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
if (subtitleFile.exists()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Subtitle already exists");
    return subtitleFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
Log.d(TAG, "Subtitle does not exists, copy it from res/raw");

// Copy the file from the res/raw folder to your app folder on the
// device
InputStream inputStream = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(subtitleFile, false);
    copyFile(inputStream, outputStream);
    return subtitleFile.getAbsolutePath();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    closeStreams(inputStream, outputStream);
}
return "";
}


private void copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
    throws IOException {
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int length = -1;
while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
}


// A handy method I use to close all the streams
private void closeStreams(Closeable... closeables) {
if (closeables != null) {
    for (Closeable stream : closeables) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to use Uri instead of `R.raw.sub`. How can i convert `getSubtitleFile(R.raw.sub)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading file from network use for e.g. URLConnection (you can use .getInputStream()). For details see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html .

You can call then

```
File dest = new File("destination on SD card");
copyFile(urlConnection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(dest));
```

and later use same file in player as:

```
player.addTimedTextSource(dest.getAbsolutePath(),
            MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can read subtitle now. You saved my life, But i have a little problem here. I used for "destination on SC card" : 
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and  copyFile(urlConnection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(dest))
It gave java.io.FileNotFoundEception:/mnt/sdcard
Can you help me for that ?

Comment: You should read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html Generally getExternalStorageDirectory is returning folder, so you might want to do like File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); File dest = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"fileName.txt"); Also you should check if SD card is mounted, etc... Check above link.

Comment: It made me crazy, i fixed but now it is giving Java.io.IOException stream closed. I used stream close but it did nothing, still the same error. Used code : 
`File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File dest = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"filename.srt");
try{
copyFile(urlConnection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(dest));}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {           closeStreams(urlConnection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(dest));
       }`

Comment: In which line is throwing IOException? Also with this code you have resource leak. You are not closing output stream, because you passed new instance to closeStreams() instead of this one that was used also in copyFile().

Comment: oh I know i'm sorry i changed 'new' already.
i did debug my project a hundred times and finally i understood my problem, my problem is about the player. it is giving some ridiculous error, and noone share the exact solution of (Media Error (1, -2147483648)) error. Now I'm trying to play video with single project,  just playing video from url with 'MediaPlayer' Object. If i success then i will try to add subtitle with your way. Thank you again, If i have a question i will ask to you=)